# How to detect if a member of a class was invoked inside or outside of that class?

Tags: javascript, class, protected

My JavaScript protected member implementation for a `Super` class (lines 3-47) below uses `#` (lines 4-5) to make private members, `$` (lines 4-5) as a protected member marker, and returns a `Proxy` object (lines 10-45) inside the `Super` class constructor to dynamically handle any protected member access.

The protected members of `Super` class are inherited in my `Sub` class (lines 49-59), but the problem is, these protected members are also accessible outside of the class (lines 65-66, 74-75, 81-82) because I am unable to detect in lines 14 and 30 if these protected members were invoked inside or outside of the class.

So, in this context, how to detect if a member of a class was invoked inside or outside of that class?

**JavaScript Code**

```js
 1 'use strict';
 2 
 3 class Super {
 4   #$fieldActualProtected = 0;
 5   #$methodActualProtected() {
 6     console.log('__methodActualProtected()__');
 7   }
 8 
 9   constructor() {
10     const target = this;
11     const handler =
12       {
13         get(target, key, receiver) {
14           if (key[0] === '$') {
15             let member;
16 
17             try {
18               member = eval(`target.#${key}`);
19             }
20             finally {
21               // Nothing here, just syntax requirement
22             }
23 
24             return member;
25           }
26 
27           return Reflect.get(...arguments);
28         },
29         set(target, key, value, receiver) {
30           if (key[0] === '$') {
31             try {
32               eval(`target.#${key} = ${value}`);
33             }
34             finally {
35               // Nothing here, just syntax requirement
36             }
37 
38             return true;
39           }
40 
41           return Reflect.set(...arguments);
42         },
43       };
44 
45     return new Proxy(target, handler);
46   }
47 }
48 
49 class Sub extends Super {
50   constructor() {
51     super();
52   }
53 
54   subMethod(value) {
55     this.$fieldActualProtected = value;
56     console.log(this.$fieldActualProtected);
57     this.$methodActualProtected();
58   }
59 }
60 
61 console.dir(Super);
62 console.group(`SUP_OBJECT`);
63   let sup = new Super();
64   console.dir(sup);
65   // sup.$fieldActualProtected = 1;
66   // sup.$methodActualProtected();
67 console.groupEnd();
68 
69 console.dir(Sub);
70 console.group(`SUB1_OBJECT`);
71   let sub1 = new Sub();
72   console.dir(sub1);
73   sub1.subMethod(2);
74   // console.log(sub1.$fieldActualProtected);
75   // console.log(sub1.$methodActualProtected);
76 console.groupEnd();
77 console.group(`SUB2_OBJECT`);
78   let sub2 = new Sub();
79   console.dir(sub2);
80   sub2.subMethod(3);
81   // console.log(sub2.$fieldActualProtected);
82   // console.log(sub2.$methodActualProtected);
83 console.groupEnd();
```

**Console Output**
![Console output of the JavaScript code] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn6FC.png)

Comment: You can't detect it. Use TypeScript.

Comment: TypeScript access modifiers are all public members in JavaScript which is really disappointing.

Comment: That's pretty common for compiled languages, e.g. access modifiers in C++ don't exist at runtime, only at compile time. AFAIK it's the same for Java. Why do you want to waste time and performance for those checks at runtime?

Comment: I am just trying out if I can implement a proper protected members in JavaScript, I am actually contented with private members. =)

Comment: You asked a specific question. I answered that question and gave you an alternative. I think, that's the best you can achieve. JavaScript doesn't support `protected` and AFAIK you can't detect whether a member of a class was invoked inside or outside that class. Older runtime engines don't support `private` and won't block access. TypeScript allows `private` and `protected` in these engines, too.

Comment: I would even say, you shouldn't use JavaScript for real projects in 2022. Type checking is far more important and helpful than access modifiers.